# How to use Version method 'valueOf(String)'

Tags: java, search, lucene

Wondering if anyone can tell me how to use the Apache Lucene method 'valueOf(String)' for Version?  Is this used to return the current version that should be used from the enum?

http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_1_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/util/Version.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)

For example, does:

```
Version.valueOf("StandardAnalyzer");
```

return the emum version that should be used with the StandardAnalyzer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think that this way you need: probe it

```
for(Version v : Version.valueOf("StandardAnalyzer")) System.out.println(v);
```

Answer (score 0):

This `valueOf` method is defined for every method, and simply converts a string like `"LUCENE_24"` to the corresponding enum constant `LUCENE_24`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the enum is there to let you safely pick the version you want to use. I guess you're supposed to go with the latest one if you're starting from scratch, but otherwise you are supposed to make a willing choice to upgrade from one version to another.
They deprecated the LUCENE_CURRENT constant so that you don't get silently "updated" when picking a new version of the library.

So basically I would pass Version.LUCENE_31 as a configuration for a new project. The enum can also be used to compare two versions with the onOrAfter method.

Still to answer you question, I think (but cannot test right now) that if for some reason you want to use the valueOf method you'd have to pass a string with the version name. For example Version.valueOf("LUCENE_23"). Of course this would be useful if your version name comes from a config file.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I am using version 3.1.0 of Lucene, and the reason I posted is because whenever I used the Version.LUCENE_31 for StandardAnalyzer, I get the exception:       org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/util/Version

Comment: Oh. This is another issue. Is it the only lucene class giving you this error ?